# How do I convert a Map to List in Java?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections

How do I convert a `Map<key,value>` to a `List<value>`? Should I iterate over all map values and insert them into a list?

Comment: I think it's not a good model if one has to convert map into list. One should write the code in such manner that this situation doesn't arrise.

Answer (score 1524, accepted):

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```

assuming:

```
Map<Key,Value> map;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming the cast from `Collection` to `List` would work.

Comment: I suspect the reason it doesn't work is because the collection returned by values() is dependent on the underlying Map; by making a copy constructor call instead, you allocate storage and copy the values into that storage, thus breaking the connection...

Comment: If we have LinkedHashMap - will the order leave the same?

Comment: @user2022068 yes, order should be preserved with LinkedHashMap.

Comment: @SheldonR. yes - the collections returned by `keySet()` and `values()` are generally shim objects that give a Set or Collection view of the underlying structure (`keySet()` returns a Set to emphasize no dupes). For `values()`, the returned object _may_ be a `List`, but often won't be. Creating a real List, as you say, breaks the link which means you're no longer dependent on the original Map. 
Sometimes though, you only need a List because some API requires one - reinforcing the rule that a good API should require only the most abstract interfaces it can get away with...

Comment: That's perfect, just let's use the diamond operator in the ArrayList constructor: List<Value> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

Comment: In my case (Java 8, IntellijJ) the compiler just fails with type inferring `new ArrayList<SomeInterface>(map.values())`; have to change it to `new ArrayList(map.values())` and only get a warning is shown.

Comment: @WesternGun Try `new ArrayList<>(map.values())`, this will get rid of all warnings

Answer (score 144):

The issue here is that [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) has two values (a key and value), while a [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) only has one value (an element).

Therefore, the best that can be done is to either get a `List` of the keys or the values. (Unless we make a wrapper to hold on to the key/value pair).

Say we have a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("Hello", "World");
m.put("Apple", "3.14");
m.put("Another", "Element");
```

The keys as a `List` can be obtained by creating a new [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) from a [`Set`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) returned by the [`Map.keySet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) method:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(m.keySet());
```

While the values as a `List` can be obtained creating a new `ArrayList` from a [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) returned by the [`Map.values`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) method:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(m.values());
```

The result of getting the `List` of keys:

```
Apple
Another
Hello
```

The result of getting the `List` of values:

```
3.14
Element
World
```

Comment: It should be noted that the order of values returned by those methods is *not defined* and for `HashMap` and similar un-sorted `Map` implementations it will be effectively random.

Comment: Yes, you would have to know it is a LinkedHashMap or something of that sort.  The problem with the original question is that the question is misstated, that is it needs editing.  The question is not to convert a Map to a List, but rather how to get the values of the map as a List.  The method values gives you a Collection, but not a list, and hence the need for a neat little trick.

Comment: I think you could add to your answer what @M0les says: That you would need to "go via" SortedMap somehow. Either start with a concrete SortedMap implementation (Such as TreeMap) or insert your input Map into a SortedMap before converting that to List

Answer (score 68):

Using the Java 8 Streams API.

```
List<Value> values = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I prefer the accepted, constructor-based answer. Streams should be for simplifying code.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, for the task of getting a List of values from Map the constructor seems to be simplier. However if you are using Streams extensivly in a codebase it's better to stay consistent.

Comment: when i use this get an error if I am fetching huge amount of data ..thread is looping on
java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3.makeSink(Unknown Source). If
threads loop infinitely, CPU consumption will start to spike up.
Looping threads stack trace are given below, examine it

Comment: I also like this code, but IntelliJ IDE suggests to change the code like this:

```java
List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 30):

`map.entrySet()` gives you a collection of `Map.Entry` objects containing both key and value. you can then transform this into any collection object you like, such as `new ArrayList(map.entrySet())`;

Answer (score 26):

a list of what ?

Assuming `map` is your instance of `Map`

- `map.values()` will return a `Collection` containing all of the map's values.
- `map.keySet()` will return a `Set` containing all of the map's keys.

Answer (score 15):

I guess you want to convert the values contained in the `Map` to a `list`? Easiest is to call the `values()` method of the `Map` interface. This will return the `Collection` of value objects contained in the `Map`.

Note that this `Collection` is backed by the `Map` object and any changes to the `Map` object will reflect here. So if you want a separate copy not bound to your `Map` object, simply create a new `List` object like an `ArrayList` passing the value `Collection` as below.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("java", 20);
    map.put("C++", 45);

    Set <Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();

    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
```

we can have both key and value pair in list.Also can get key and value using Map.Entry by iterating over list.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ensure the values in the resultant `List<Value>` are in the key-ordering of the input `Map<Key, Value>`, you need to "go via" `SortedMap` somehow.

Either *start* with a concrete `SortedMap` implementation (Such as `TreeMap`) or insert your input `Map` into a `SortedMap` before converting that to `List`. e.g.:

```
Map<Key,Value> map;
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>( new TreeMap<Key Value>( map ));
```

Otherwise you'll get whatever native ordering the `Map` implementation provides, which can often be something other than the natural key ordering (Try `Hashtable` or `ConcurrentHashMap`, for variety).

Answer (score 5):

```
// you can use this
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());

// or you may use 
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
list.add(entry.getValue());    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 Map<String, String > map = new HapshMap<String, String>;
 map.add("one","java");
 map.add("two", "spring");
 Set<Entry<String, String>> set = map.entrySet();
 List<Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>>    (set);
 for(Entry<String, String> entry : list) {
   System.out.println(entry.getKey());
   System.out.println(entry.getValue());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Object> convertMapToList(Map<Object, Object> map){
    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary cast here?

Comment: The object change you used example: String , Integer etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the generic method to get values from map.

```
public static <T> List<T> ValueListFromMap(HashMap<String, T> map) {
    List<T> thingList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, T> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        thingList.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    return thingList;
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize ArrayList with the size of Map, if you have a map got like 1 Million records, good luck with having .add() dealing with resizing the array over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an *immutable* copy of the values:

```
List<Value> list = List.copyOf(map.values())
```

Comment: Why You not mention the package of ```List.copyOf```?

Comment: because it is the usual `java.util.List`?

Comment: What? but popup .class only java.util.List.class