# Iterate an ArrayList of HashMap objects

Tags: android, hashmap, iteration

I have an ArrayList of HashMap objects as result of parsing an XML file. I would like to create an ArrayList of values for a certain key for display in a ListView. Here is what I have so far:

```
    // Initialize the guideList ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> guideList = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String,Object> dict = null;

    // Get the data - returns an ArrayList
    Object obj = plist.getConfigurationObject("array");

    // make sure an ArrayList was returned
    if (obj instanceof ArrayList) {

        // initialize Iterator
        Iterator itr = ((ArrayList) obj).iterator();
        int i = 0;

        // Loop through and create guideList ArrayList
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            itr.next();
            dict = ((ArrayList<HashMap>) obj).get(i++);
            Object guideNo = dict.get("GUIDE_NO");
            guideList.add( "Guide "+guideNo.toString() );
        }
    }
```

This code does work, but is it the most efficient?

Comment: Are you having some trouble with it this way? Or is it working properly but you are just wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  This code does work, I'm concerned about performance on larger data sets.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above question which is about retrieving a list values and keys from a Map. While I'm looking for the most efficient way to iterate through an Array of Maps.