# Put map's value in a list

Tags: java

I have a hashmap that contains, person Id as key, and person object as value.

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<String,Person>();
```

The person object (map's value) contains a person Id instance variable that I'd like to compare with user input. My idea is to create an arraylist from the map's values as mentioned here - [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java), so I can check if the arraylist.contains(userInput).

However, I need a arraylist of strings that contains Person.getPersonId(),please help me here. Can I do it in one step? If there is a better alternative then, please suggest.

Comment: Why would you want to convert the values to an `ArrayList`?  Are you just trying to find a particular key in the map?  Can't you just use `get` for this?

Comment: Yes - can you verify whether the `String` key from the `Map` is, in-fact, the same as ther `personId` field on the `Persion` objects?  If so, then all this list stuff is completely backwards and unnecessary - you are completely ignoring the intended function of the `Map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, you need to get `Person` values from `personMap`.

```
List<Person> persons =personMap.values();
```

To get arraylist of strings that contains Person.getPersonId(), you need to do following steps.

```
List<String> personIds=new ArrayList<>();
for(Person p: persons){ // Iterate over persons List
  if(p.getPersonId()!=null){ //Check the personId from Person
    personIds.add(p.getPersonId());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(personMap.values());
List<String> idList = personList.stream().map(Person::getPersonId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi, he wants `List` of person Id

Comment: Hi Danh and Mani, the answer was modified. Thanks!