# Get values from Java Map

Tags: java

I have this simple problem which I cannot solve.

I have this Map which stores the sessions:

```
Map<String, ActiveConnections>
```

I want to get all String values and insert them into ArrayList.

Can you tell em how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

Comment: @Bishan Not a duplicate of that one, IMHO.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yeah. you are correct. not a **duplicate** of that one. but **possible duplicate** of that one. :)

Comment: @Bishan Fair enough :) Agreed.

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the keys using the [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method and create a new `ArrayList` with that.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 2):

Map contains a method called  [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) , Which

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map.

Then use that `Set` to build your `List`, by using constructor or using `addAll` method

```
keyList.addAll(set);
```