# Why don't TreeMap.values() reflect the order in which elements were originally added?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I need a `data structure` that will perform both the role of a `lookup map` by key as well as be able to be convertable into a `sorted list`.  The data that goes in is a very siple code-description pair (e.g. *M/Married*, *D/Divorced* etc).  The lookup requirement is in order to get the description once the user makes a selection in the UI, whose value is the code.  The sorted list requirement is in order to feed the data into UI components (JSF) which take [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) as input and the values always need to be displayed in the same order (alphabetical order of description).

The first thing that came to mind was a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).  So I retrieve the data from my DB in the order I want it to be shown in the UI and load it into my tree map, keyed by the code so that I can later look up descriptions for further display once the user makes selections.  As for getting a sorted list out of that same map, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java), I am doing the following:

```
List<CodeObject> list = new ArrayList<CodeObject>(map.values());
```

However, the list is not sorted in the same order that they were put into the map.  The map is declared as a SortedMap and implemented as a TreeMap:

```
SortedMap<String, CodeObject> map = new TreeMap<String, CodeObject>().
```

`CodeObject` is a simple `POJO` containing just the code and description and corresponding getters (setters in through the constructor), a list of which is fed to UI components, which use the code as the value and description for display.  I used to use just a List and that work fine with respect to ordering but a List does not provide an efficient interface for looking up a value by key and I now do have that requirement.

So, my questions are:

1. If TreeMap is supposed to be a map in the ordered of item addition, why isn's `TreeMap.values()` in the same order?
2. What should I do to fulfill my requirements explained above, i.e. have a data structure that will serve as both a lookup map AND a sorted collection of elements? Will TreeMap do it for me if I use it differently or do I need an altogether different approach?

Comment: I think you are confusing `TreeMap` with `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: TreeMaps aren't ordered by insertion order.

Comment: I was always told that TreeMap guarantees the order of entries in which they were added

Comment: "If TreeMap is supposed to be a map in the ordered of item addition", how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- how is "addition" different from "insertion" ?

Comment: @amphibient: What I meant was that the order `TreeMap` guarantees isn't the order of addition/insertion/whatever you want to call it. At all. `TreeMap` sorts by the *natural order of the keys* -- that is, `compareTo`-style. So say your keys are strings. The sort will be (largely) alphabetic. Or say they're numeric: The sort will be by number.

Comment: well, that is not the order in which they were added.  but i get it

Comment: @amphibient: My original comment above (now deleted) was really poorly-phrased. Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was that it guarantees **an** order, but the order it guarantees is not the order of addition/insertion.

Comment: I figured.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @amphibient If you were always told that, you were misinformed. I suggest you misunderstood, or got confused with LinkedHashMap. If TreeMap was meant to behave as you describe, it would be documented, and it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TreeMap` maintain's the key's natural order. You can even order it (with a bit more manipulation and custom definition of a comparator) by the natural order/reverse order of the value. But this is not the same as saying "Insertion order". To maintain the insertion order you need to use `LinkedHashMap`. Java `LinkedHashMap` is a subclass of `HashMap` - the analogy is the same as `LinkedList` where you maintain the trace of the next node. However, it says it cannot "Guarantee" that the order is maintained, so don't ask your money back if you suddenly see an insertion order is maintained with `HashMap`

Comment: Actually you can only *attempt* to order by value with a "smart" hack, but the attempt only sometimes appears to work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik      http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-by-keys-and-values/

Comment: What's the relevance of that page? It shows how to sort a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 3):

`TreeMap`'s documentation says:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So unless you're providing a `Comparator` and tracking the insertion order and using it in that `Comparator`, you'll get the natural order of the keys, not the order in which the keys were inserted.

If you want insertion order, [as davide said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132171/why-dont-treemap-values-reflect-the-order-in-which-elements-were-originally-a/29132238#comment46490301_29132171), you can use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order...This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is *re-inserted* into the map.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)
See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap) as well.