# Java 8: Convert a map with string values to a list containg a different type

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, map-function

I have this `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = ...
```

And I have this class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

I want to convert the map to `List<Foo>`. Is there a convenient manner in Java 8 to do this?

Currently, my way is:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>((int) map.values().flatMap(e->e.stream()).count()));

for(Integer id : map.keySet()){
    for(String name : map.get(id)){
        Foo foo = new Foo(id,name);
        list.add(foo);  
    }
}
```

I feel it's too cumbersome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

Comment: No it's not duplicate.

Comment: @zhugowei I have to agree with you. I've edited the question to prevent the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have the following:

```
List<Foo> list = map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(name -> new Foo(e.getKey(), name)))
                    .collect(toList());
```

For each entry of the map, we create a Stream of the value and map it to the corresponding `Foo` and then flatten it using `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for your version being cumbersome is that you have decided to calculate the capacity of the `ArrayList` first. Since this calculation requires iterating over the entire map, there is unlikely to be any benefit in this. You definitely should not do such a thing unless you have proved using a proper benchmark that it is needed.

I can't see anything wrong with just using your original version but with the parameterless constructor for `ArrayList` instead. If you also get rid of the redundant local variable `foo`, it's actually fewer characters (and clearer to read) than the stream version.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. but It is difficult to hold back not to optimize

Answer (score 0):

```
final Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> new Foo(e.getKey(), s)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```