# How to convert Values in a Hashmap to a List<String>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Hashmap of type

```
Map<String, List<String>> adminErrorMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to be able to iterate thru the entire hashmap and get all the values to a single `List<String>`. The Keys are irrelevant.

I have done something like this:

```
List<String> adminValues = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : adminErrorMap.entrySet()) {                
         adminValues.add(entry.getValue().toString());
    }
System.out.println(adminValues);
```

**Output**

> [[{description=File Path, value=PurchaseOrder.plsql},
>   {description=Component, value=PURCH}, {description=Commit Date,
>   value=Thu May 05 00:32:01 IST 2016}],[{description=File Path,
>   value=CustomerOrder.plsql}, {description=Component, value=COMP},
>   {description=Commit Date, value=Thu June 05 00:32:01 IST 2016}]]

As you can see, there are [] inside a main [].

How to have all values inside one []. Like shown below;

Or is there any other way to implement this?

> [{description=File Path, value=PurchaseOrder.plsql},
>   {description=Component, value=PURCH}, {description=Commit Date,
>   value=Thu May 05 00:32:01 IST 2016},{description=File Path,
>   value=CustomerOrder.plsql}, {description=Component, value=COMP},
>   {description=Commit Date, value=Thu June 05 00:32:01 IST 2016}]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `adminValues.add(entry.getKey());` or something like that? You can't put a `List<String>` into a container that's expecting a `String`

Comment: That's if i want the keys. But i want only the Values of all keys

Comment: Then why do you declare `adminValues` as being of type `List<String>` instead of `List< List<String> >`?

Comment: Ah ha! I see you got a point there! thanks :)

Comment: I'll be posting my comment as an answer if it works for you then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java), which says to use `new ArrayList<String>(map.values())`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `addAll` instead of `add`, in order to add all the `String`s of all the `List<String>`s to a single `List<String>` :

```
for (List<String> value : adminErrorMap.values())   
{                
     adminValues.addAll(value);
}
```

Comment: I think this code is incorrect. It seems none of the up-voters for this answer noticed that `adminValues` is a container for `String` objects, *not* a container for `List<String>`, i.e. the declaration is not `List< List<String> > adminValues`

Comment: @ray It is correct. addAll accepts a Collection and adds all the elements of that Collection to the List. Therefore, you call `adminValues.addAll(value);` to add all the Strings of the `value` List to the output `List<String>`.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm up late, but `adminValues` is expecting `String`s to be added, yet the `value` variable is not a `String`, it's a `List<String>`, which is what makes this look odd to me.

Comment: @ray Note that I'm using addAll, not add. addAll expects a  Collection of the same element type as the List to which you are adding the elements. Therefore you can call `addAll` for a `List<String>` and pass to it another `List<String>`.

Comment: @ray Here's [the JavaDoc for same](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Very well. I'll go take my pills now -_-

Answer (score 9):

In Java8, you can use functional to do that:

```
adminErrorMap.values().forEach(adminValues::addAll);
```

Answer (score 8):

### A simple way would be:

```
new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

For JDK 8 and above this can also be done as:

```
map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to flatten the collection. In Java8:

```
    final Map<String, List<String>> adminErrorMap = ImmutableMap.of(
            "a", Lists.newArrayList("first", "second"),
            "b", Lists.newArrayList("third")
    );

    final List<String> results = adminErrorMap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It prints:

```
first
second
third
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue in your declaration types:

```
Map<String, List<String>> adminErrorMap = new HashMap<>();
List<String> adminValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

Your `adminValues` is expecting `String` objects to be added, but you're trying to add objects of type `List<String>` into it:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : adminErrorMap.entrySet())               
    adminValues.add(entry.getValue().toString());
```

The `entry.getValue()`, based on the declaration of `adminErrorMap`, does *not* return an object of type `String`. Instead, it returns another `List<String>`, which is not at all what's expected. You're simply calling `toString()` on that `List<String>` object, which is probably not what you really wanted to do.

Since you can't put a `List<String>`-typed object into a container that is expecting `String`-typed objects, you should be using `entry.getKey()` instead:

```
adminValues.add(entry.getKey());
```

Perhaps the following might be more useful, if I recall my Java correctly:

```
for (String key : adminErrorMap.keySet())
    adminValues.add(key);
```

---

Edit for this comment:

> i want only the Values of all keys

Since each key can have multiple values associated with it, given that they're of type `List<String>`, then you should consider something closer what [Eran proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043736/4594973):

```
for (List<String> values : adminErrorMap.values())               
    adminValues.addAll(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aint we doing this

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapKeyList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Iterator it = mapKeyList.entrySet().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            List<String> strList = (List<String>) pair.getValue();

            Iterator<String> strIt= strList.iterator();
            while(strIt.hasNext()){
                String str = strIt.next();
                finalList.add(str);
            }

        }
```

I know complexity is going to be in **order of n*n** but we are getting the expecting output.

Comment: Your code is much too long. Since Java 1.5, the Iterator class is only used in very special situations, and this isn’t one of them.

Comment: This code is unnecessarily long/verbose for what's actually needed, and its time complexity is not great either.

Comment: but if we are getting the expected output then its ok to go with this code, I think..