# Create only 1 list from a map where map value is list using JAVA 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map, where the "value" is a List of projects:

```
Map<User, List<Project>> projectsMap = ...
```

I want to extract from the map the projects but in only and just 1 List of projects:

I've already seen answers but they don't apply to my case. 
I don't want this result:

```
List<List<Project>> theValueOfTheMap;
```

The result I want is:

```
List<Project> projects = ... // All the project in the value's map
```

How can I achieve this using JAVA 8 Streams?
Thanks. 
Leonardo.

Comment: `projectsMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

Comment: @Holger, your answer is what I need. Why did not you answer in the answers section? thanks.

Comment: I’m quite sure that this is a duplicate of a previous question…

Comment: @Holger, it is not. I have a Collection as the values in the map. The previous question is converting a simple Map to a list. I can't make `List<Connection> temp = new ArrayList<>(membersConnections.values()); ` for may case. Previous question has same answer you gave, but how would I know it will work for a Key, Value map where the value is a Collection? I saw the question, did not applied for my case, so I did not had a look in the answers.

Comment: I’m not talking about the link, DimaSan has posted. This topic has been covered before, for sure. I just didn’t had the time to search for a best match yet, that’s why I posted the comment, to give you a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Holger for the answer.

```
List<Project> projects = projectsMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
.collect(‌​Collectors.toList())‌​;
```

Code to avoid NullPointerException in case a Collection in the value map is Null:

```
projectsMap.values().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
.flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
projectsMap.values().stream().reduce((v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Comment: Doesn’t work and would be a performance disaster (incl. potential stack overflows), if it worked.

Comment: I agree with @Holger

Answer (score -1):

Map has a methos to retrieve all the values from it.

You just need to call `projectsMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())` to make a List os all objects of the map values.

EDIT: forgot to add flatMap, as Holger commented.

Comment: It returns `List<List<Project>>`.