# Convert map into a list in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a map into a list. I'm trying to use the forEach() method.But i don't know where i'm going wrong.Can someone help? Also after converting them to lists,i want to access their index.How to do?

For eg: I have 2 maps

```
Map foodMap = {
     value:50
     title:'food',
}

Map travelMap={
     value:30,
     title:'travel'
}

List<String> sampleList = [];
```

I want to convert my two maps into list and add them into sampleList.

Comment: you have `Map.keys` and `Map.values` properties

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html#instance-properties

Comment: Like this?  datamap.values.forEach((p)=> sampleList.add(p));

Comment: How do you want to add them? Maps and lists are structured differently, so you cannot just "convert" them. Can you precisely explain what you expect to have in the end?

Comment: like that `datamap.values`

Comment: I want to convert those two maps into a list and merge them into one list and then want to access each element's index in that list.

Comment: so read [Iterable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html) official documentation - it has  methods for merging two `Iterable`s and converting to a list

Comment: I'm not able to understand it. Can you try and share the code?

Comment: `var iterable1 = Iterable.generate(3, (i) => i);
  var iterable2 = Iterable.generate(3, (i) => 10 * i);
  var iterable3 = iterable1.followedBy(iterable2).toList();
  print(iterable3);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a Map to List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026723/how-to-convert-a-map-to-list-in-java)

Comment: or even: `var iterable3 = iterable1.toList() + iterable2.toList();`

Comment: I think, what you want is to merge list of json data to single map. like `{"food" : 50, "travel": 30}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map foodMap = {
  "value": 50,
  "title": 'food',
};

Map travelMap = {
  "value": 30,
  "title": 'travel',
};

Map<String, double> sampleList = {};
```

I think, this is how you want to add two maps:

```
void _addToMappedList(Map<String, double> sampleList, Map newData) {
  String title = newData["title"];
  double value = double.tryParse(newData["value"].toString());

  sampleList[title] = value;
}

....

_addToMappedList(sampleList, foodMap);
_addToMappedList(sampleList, travelMap);
```

To merge list of maps to single

```
List<Map> mapList = [/*Contains list of maps*/];
....
mapList.forEach((mapItem) => _addToMappedList(sampleList, travelMap))
```

To access their index

```
print(sampleList.entries.elementAt(1));
```